# list of switches as the pictures shows

Tags: java, android, android-layout

I'm developing an android software and I need in the setting part this same exact design.
I have customized a switch but I could not reach the same result.

This is my code:

settings_Activity:

```xml
<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_gravity="center"
    android:gravity="center">

    <Switch
        android:id="@+id/switch2"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:checked="true"
        android:text="Econet Mode"
        android:track="@drawable/switch_track"
        android:thumb="@drawable/swithc_thumb"
        />

</LinearLayout>
```

switch_thumb:

```xml
<stroke android:width="4dp" android:color="@android:color/transparent"/>
```

switch_track:

```xml
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
```

```xml
<shape android:shape="rectangle">
    <corners android:radius="20dp"></corners>
    <solid android:color="@color/colorPrimary"></solid>
</shape>
```

```xml
<item android:state_checked="false">

    <shape android:shape="rectangle">
        <corners android:radius="20dp"></corners>
        <solid android:color="@color/colorGrey"></solid>
    </shape>
</item>
```

This is the final result I want to see:

[image: Expected result]

Comment: [use this library](https://github.com/Angads25/android-toggle) for easy and simplified output of your requirement.

Comment: Hey ,You can use toggle button and give custom images for on and off toggle.You can create image as you want and give it to toggle buttons. I have used in one of my project if you want to use toggle then let me know i will post my code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

create drawable **thumb_selector.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <item android:state_checked="false">
        <shape android:dither="true" android:shape="rectangle" android:useLevel="false" android:visible="true">
            <solid android:color="#ffffff" />
            <corners android:radius="100dp" />
            <size android:width="24dp" android:height="25dp" />
            <stroke android:width="4dp" android:color="#0000ffff" />
        </shape>
    </item>
</selector>
```

create drawable **track_selector.xml**

```
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <item android:state_checked="true">
        <shape android:dither="true" android:shape="rectangle" android:useLevel="false" android:visible="true">
            <solid android:color="@color/text_pink" />
            <corners android:radius="25dp" />
            <size android:width="2dp" android:height="18dp" />
        </shape>
    </item>
    <item android:state_checked="false">
        <shape android:dither="true" android:shape="rectangle" android:useLevel="false" android:visible="true">

            <corners android:radius="25dp" />
            <size android:width="2dp" android:height="18dp" />
            <stroke
                android:width="2dp"
                android:color="@color/white" />
        </shape>
    </item>
</selector>
```

use it like this

```
<android.support.v7.widget.SwitchCompat
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:checked="true"
                    android:padding="5dp"
                    android:thumb="@drawable/thumb_selector"
                    app:track="@drawable/track_selector" />
```

Comment: did you applied the same way i did ? see **app:track** annotation

Comment: yep, exactly as you write it.

Comment: Can you show me how you declare the app namespace?? Usually its is declare on the top layout of xml.. It should res-auto

Comment: this is how it looks acording to your code
https://imgur.com/dvqBK5m.jpg

Comment: @elhsaynifouad You need to play with width although the outcome is pretty similar to the design requirement